Allow Teams Bot to authenticate to App Service after IDP setup
I have a server hosted on Azure App Service that has 2 endpoints:
/api/messages - Messaging endpoint connected to Azure Bot Service for the operations of a MS Teams bot.
/notifications - Checks for the current available users and pings them. To invoke it at regular intervals, we have a logic app (referred as api-caller in the screenshot below) hit this endpoint every 6 hours.
To add security to these endpoints, we created an IDP on the app service by following these instructions.
This added the Azure auth to both the endpoints, and the logic app is able to authenticate and hit the /notifications endpoint successfully. However, it made the Azure bot unresponsive, because Azure bot is unable to authenticate into the /api/messages endpoint.
Here is a screenshot of the current configuration of the IDP in the App Service. As an attempt to solve the issue, we tried to add the following to the allow list:

App ID of the Entra App that is created along with the Azure Bot Service.

Client ids of MS Teams app and web application.


Screenshot of IDP configuration inside App Service
Even after this the messaging endpoint still returns 401: Unauthorized status to the invocations from Azure Bot. How do we make the endpoint accessible to the Azure Bot? Are there any extra configurations to be made?
Thanks in advance.
